# After moving magento from subdomain to subfolder my account and log in redirect wrong

Tags: magento

After moving the magento installation from mysubdomain.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/magento the customer account links redirect to www.mydomain.com/customer/account instead of www.mydomain.com/magento/customer/account. Everything else works perfectly fine, but those links don't work. Is there any way to change those links without a full reinstalation? The links that don't work are my account, log in, sign up. Suprisingly, the log out button works just fine.
This is my webstore http://www.ivankamoda.hr/webshop/. I have searched the web for two days but i haven't found anything that could fix my problem. I hope someone here will know the answer.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Have you completely cleared your Magento cache after making the move? Also, have you tried modifying the rewrite rules in your .htaccess file to reflect your subdirectory?

Comment: I have, both the sessions and the cache. There should be no need for modifying the rewrite rules, but i have also tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: You said those links redirect.  When you click them, are they going to the correct path (the `<a>` tag has the correct URL), THEN the page is redirected?  Or does the `<a>` for the account links just have the wrong URL.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The <a> tag has the wrong URL. I still have no idea why that happens. It gets the customer/account/customerid link from php, but it should get only that part, and it seems it gets the whole link (http://www.mydomain.com/customer/account/customerid.

Answer (score 1):

First, I can confirm that it's not need to reinstall magento after changing domain.
Your problems may be caused by template designer hard code the links.

Here is my steps to change domain:

1. Update unsecure_url, secure_url in core_config_data table.
2. Clear all caches

Comment: The links aren't hardcoded, the template uses the standard customer.xml and top.links.phtml files. 
And I have followed those steps, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The url of your website should be stored twice in the table "core_config_data". Change that to the new path, and it should work fine.

Comment: I have already updated the all of the urls in configuration -> web, and checked all of them in core_config_data and all of them were updated. In addition, if the core_config_data url was wrong, nothing on the webstore would work. But thank you for your response.